# wp_mail doen't send mails with attachment

Tags: attachments, wp-mail

On my site I have two forms witch send email. The one with no attachment needed is sent correctly, but the other one which has an attachment does not get sent. I am using SMTP config with Postman SMTP plugin.

```php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/CV/'.basename($_FILES['cv']['name']));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["lm"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/lm/'.basename($_FILES['lm']['name']));
    
$attachments = array(
    WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/CV/".$_FILES["cv"]["name"],
    WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/lm/".$_FILES["lm"]["name"]
    );
```

This is the code I use for storing and reaching the attachments and simply using the wp_mail function to send it like this:

```php
$sent=wp_mail($s, $subject, $message, $headers,$attachments);
```

On the other form I am using the same code just without the $attachments variable.
The one without attachments get sent but the other one does not.
Can anyone help me find my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.

```
<?php
$attachments = array();

array_push($attachments, WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/my-first-attachment.docx' );
array_push($attachments, WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/my-second-attachment.zip' );

$to="my-friend@some-doamin.info";
$subject="Online: multiple attachment demo through wp_mail of wordpress";
$message="This is testing";
$headers = 'From: NAPSWI online <online@napswi.org>';
get_header();
if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments) ) {
 // the message was sent...
 echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
} else {
 // the message was not sent...
 echo 'The message was not sent!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work :( the mail doesn't get sent

Answer (score 0):

I would also try adding to the array using the fashion below. (see my example)  try using the actual location of the 2 files as just a test, then insert the PHP.
I've outlined 3 different options to try out, but of course you should use the actual URL on your site to those `files/`

```
<?php
$attachments = array(); //may or may not be needed.

$att1 = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/my-1st-attachemnt.zip';
$att2 = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/my-second-attachment.zip';

$attachments[] = $att1; //try these as working solution
$attachments[] = $att2; //try these as working solution 
$attachments[] = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/my-1st-attachemnt.zip';  //try this 2nd
$attachments[] = '/wp-content/uploads/my-second-attachment.zip';  //try this last


$to = "my-friend@some-doamin.info";
$subject = "Online: multiple attachment demo through wp_mail of wordpress";
$message = "This is testing";
$headers = 'From: NAPSWI online <online@napswi.org>';
get_header();

if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments) ) {
   // the message was sent...
   echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
} else {
   // the message was not sent...
   echo 'The message was not sent!';
}
```